# How to differentiate $\arctan(\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\cos x+\sin x})$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

**Problem:**

Differentiate with respect to $x$: $\arctan(\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\cos x+\sin x})$

**My attempt**:

Let, $y=\arctan(\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\cos x+\sin x})$

$$y=\arctan(\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\cos x+\sin x})$$

$$y=\arctan\frac{(\cos x-\sin x)^2}{2\cos2x}$$

$$y=\arctan\frac{1-\sin2x}{2\cos2x}$$

$$y=\arctan(\frac{1}{2\cos2x}-\frac{\sin2x}{2\cos2x})$$

$$y=\arctan\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{\cos2x}-\frac{\sin2x}{\cos2x})$$

$$y=\arctan\frac{1}{2}(\sec2x-\tan2x)$$

**My observations:**

Now, I could find the derivative using the brute force of chain rule, but the derivative of the above graph is [$-1$](https://www.derivative-calculator.net/#expr=%5Carctan%28%5Cfrac%7B%5Ccos%20x-%5Csin%20x%7D%7B%5Ccos%20x%2B%5Csin%20x%7D%29), so I think a much easier way to find the derivative might exist.

**Question:**

1. Is there a way to find the derivative of the above graph very easily, which is not that tedious?

Comment: Do you now how to caclculate the derivative of inverse functions?

Comment: yes, $\frac{d}{dx}\arctan(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$

Comment: Btw how did the factor 2 appeared in you denominator?

Comment: If you know the derivative of arctan, then you can simply use the chain rule.

Comment: @GáborPálovics I edited the question; I know, but it seems tedious. The derivative of the above graph is a constant (-1), so I thought that there might be a really easy way to find the derivative then.

Comment: Presumably $y=-x$ then, so I would try writing $\tan y=\dfrac{1}{(\sin(x)+\cos(x))^2}$ and using various trig identities. Edit: I'm off by a constant, but the idea stands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have $$\begin{align*}\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\cos x+\sin x}&=\frac{\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\sqrt2}}{\frac{\cos x+\sin x}{\sqrt2}}
\\&=\frac{\sin{(\frac{\pi}4}-x)}{\cos{(\frac{\pi}4}-x)}
\\&=\tan{(\frac{\pi}4}-x)\end{align*}$$
Can you proceed form here?